# "iterate" through all document fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have a collection with documents in this form:

```
{
  "fields_names": ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
  "field1": 1,
  "field2": [1, 2, 3]
  "field3": "12345"
}
```

where field1, field2, field3 are "dynamic" for each document (I have for each document the fields names in the "fields_names" array)

I would like to test whether 2 documents are equals using the aggregation framework.
I used $lookup stage for getting another documents.
My issue is: how can I "iterate" through the whole fields for my collection?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  {$match: "my_id": "test_id"},
  {$lookup:
    from: "collection"
    let: my_id: "$my_id", prev_id: "$_id"
    pipeline: [
      {$match: "my_id": "$$my_id", "_id": {$ne: "$$prev_id"}}
    ]
    as: "lookup_test"
  }
}])
```

and in the pipeline of the lookup, I would like to iterate the "fields_names" array for getting the names of the fields, and then access their value and compare between the "orig document" (not the $lookup) and the other documents ($lookup documents).
OR: just to iterate all fields (not include the "fields_names" array)

I would like to fill the "lookup_test" array with all documents which as the same fields values..

Comment: please add your expected result as per your example documents.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compare the two "partial" parts of the document meaning you'll have to ( for each document ) do this in the `$lookup`, needless to say this is going to be a -very- expensive pipeline. With that said here's how I would do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "my_id": "test_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id",
        partialRoot: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            },
            as: "fieldObj",
            cond: {
              "$setIsSubset": [
                [
                  "$$fieldObj.k"
                ],
                "$fields_names"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$id",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $size: "$$partialRoot"
                    },
                    {
                      $size: {
                        "$setIntersection": [
                          "$$partialRoot",
                          {
                            $filter: {
                              input: {
                                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
                              },
                              as: "fieldObj",
                              cond: {
                                "$setIsSubset": [
                                  [
                                    "$$fieldObj.k"
                                  ],
                                  "$fields_names"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "x"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WCSiWIw6zvA)

If you could dynamically build the query through code you could make this much more efficient by using the same match query in the `$lookup` stage like so:

```
const query = { my_id: "test_id" };

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: query
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
         ...
         pipeline: [
             { $match: query },
              ... rest of pipeline ...
         ]
      }
   }
])
```

This way you're only matching documents who at least match the initial query, this should drastically improve query performance ( obviously dependant on field x value entropy )

One more caveat to note is that if x document match you will get the same result x times, meaning you probably want to add `$limit: 1` stage to your pipeline.

---